# Connecting bluetooth headset to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I am connecting a Bluetooth headset to my Windows 7 laptop. I have to keep the window open for Bluetooth configuration in order to keep it connected; see the window in the following image:

[image]

As soon as I close the window, after a few minutes the Bluetooth is disconnected. How can I keep my Bluetooth device connected permanently with the laptop?

I am using Motrolla H350.

Comment: Have you added device in your windows by using option Add Bluetooth Device.

Comment: These are HP documents but will have information applicable to all PC's and Windows 7...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01567794&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01948661&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en

Comment: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01927258&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#N752

Comment: Yes I have added the device using add blue tooth device